# emacs on wsl2 creating directories with bad/unusable permissions

Tags: microsoft-windows, wsl

Running emacs (29.1.90) in WSL2 on Windows 11.  (Also tried 30.0.50, same results)

Got everything working smoothly but when emacs creates directories they are being created with the wrong permissions.  For example, `M-x package-list-packages` needs to create some cache directories in .emacs.d and they are created with 644 (drw-r--r--) permission instead of 755 (drwxr-xr-x) permission and as a result emacs can't use the directories (just generates errors).  All other activities, not just that package-manager package, that need to create directories have the same issue.

Prior to launching emacs I checked my umask and it was set to 0022 which looks correct. Outside of emacs all directory creations work smoothly; `mkdir dir1` creates dir1 with 755 (drwxr-xr-x) permissions as expected.

If all the directories are updated to 755 permissions (using chmod) before launching emacs then everything works smoothly and emacs is able to create the files it needs to in those directories.

```
$ wsl.exe --version
WSL version: 2.0.9.0
Kernel version: 5.15.133.1-1
WSLg version: 1.0.59
MSRDC version: 1.2.4677
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22621.2715
```

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 29.1.90
Development version 687c416ce9bf on emacs-29 branch; build date 2023-11-29.
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

Comment: What distro are you running? Because I just installed it yesterday on Windows 11 on WSL 2, same versions and everything, and it is working just fine. I´m running it on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm running as well. 

    $ wsl.exe --list
    Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
    Ubuntu (Default)

    $ wsl.exe --status
    Default Distribution: Ubuntu
    Default Version: 2
    WSL1 is not supported with your current machine configuration.
    Please enable the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" optional component to use WSL1.

    $ cat /etc/os-release
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION_ID="22.04"
    VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel pretty silly.

Just found this in my .emacs file from years ago -

`(set-default-file-modes ?\644)`

I think I added it back when I was running emacs under cygwin...

Thanks @user12593215, your feedback made me think it must be something I had done and sure enough that was it.  Once I removed it my environment seems to be working smoothly now.  Thanks!